# Create new custom post and post category of same name

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, filters, actions

I have a custom post type "Product" and want to create a post category "A Product Name" automatically on creation of a new Product so that the post category (not custom post category) would have the same name as the new Product and so that all relevant posts could be linked to the custom post type.

I was trying to hook into the wp_publish_post but apparently it has been renamed to `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}` so I imagine the tag would be publish_product?

```
    // adds category with name of product automatically
add_filter( 'publish_product', 'my_publish_product' );

function my_publish_product( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_type = 'product'; 

    if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) )
        return;

    if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status )
        return;

    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_status' => 'publish' ), array( 'ID' => $post->ID ) );

    clean_post_cache( $post->ID );

    $old_status = $post->post_status;
    $post->post_status = 'publish';
    wp_transition_post_status( 'publish', $old_status, $post );

    /** This action is documented in wp-includes/post.php */
    do_action( 'edit_post', $post->ID, $post );
    /** This action is documented in wp-includes/post.php */
    do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post, true );
    /** This action is documented in wp-includes/post.php */
    do_action( 'save_post', $post->ID, $post, true );
    /** This action is documented in wp-includes/post.php */
    do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post->ID, $post, true );

    if ( 'post' != $post_type ) {
        return;
    } else {
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_wp_insert_post($post->post_name)' );
        return;
    }
}
function my_wp_insert_post( $post_name )
{
    $my_cat = array(
  'cat_ID' => 0,
  'cat_name' => $post_name, 
  'category_parent' => 'products',
  'taxonomy' => 'category' 
  );

    wp_insert_category($my_cat);
}
```

I'm not terribly adept at using hooks and filters so apologies if this is all wrong or makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way off, if you say that [`wp_publish_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post) has been renamed to `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`. The latter actually is a hook, while the former is a function. Where the latter is part of the former, because it's part of `wp_insert_post`.

The hook `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}` is part of [`wp_transition_post_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_post_status) - additionally see the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3654). You might want to take a look at the codex article about the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/) to learn more about hooks in general. Additional specific information regarding hooks applicable when publishing, saving and so on posts - or post types - can be found at the entry about [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), besides above linked `wp_transition_post_status()`; and - as always - the source.

Regarding the code you posted, there should be no need to do `my_publish_product()` - or at least none that can be seen from your code. Your posts from the post type product are getting created, saved, updated and so on just fine I imagine.
You can just hook `my_wp_insert_post()` directly to the hook most suitable for your needs, following your code the [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) filter. Which is part of the [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3259) - and the [`wp_publish_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3355) - function. Last but not least take a look at the usage of [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

Below code exemplary outlines how to do it:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_wp_insert_post', 1, 3 );
function my_wp_insert_post( $post_id, $post, true ) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks, I guess »give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime« applies here :)

Comment: @mantis my pleasure, that was the intention

Comment: @ialocin posted my corrected version. Cheers for the fishing lesson ;)

Comment: @mantis we all have to eat, right? :) one more thing, can please add the solution you came up with as answer - thanks!

Comment: Certainly, I added it below the question but am happy to move it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @ialocin 's answer:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_wp_insert_post', 1, 2 );

    function my_wp_insert_post( $post_id, $post ) {

        $title = $post->post_title;
        $post_type = $post->post_type;
        $post_status = $post->post_status;

        // Only do this for published products 
        if ( 'product' != $post_type ) {
                return;
         } elseif ('publish' != $post_status ) {
                return;
         }

          $my_cat = array(
              'cat_name' => $title, 
              'category_parent' => 3, //cat id of all products
              'taxonomy' => 'category' 
          );

          wp_insert_category( $my_cat );
    }
```

Comment: I did a little bit of code optimization, the `get_post()` call was unnecessary, because the `$post` object is already available.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so but couldn't get it to work right without it as I was trying to add $wp_error (true) as well.